# Display only local categories or tree view in TYPO3 news creation

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have a TYPO3 v7.6.18 multi-site system with tt_news plugin for news.

Each site has its own news section with different categories like:

[image]

I would like to be able to choose from these categories, when creating a news item, but in the *Categories&Relations* (I have hidden the Relations tab, since I don't use it), I get the whole list of categories from almost all the projects (probably all, there is just a limit on how many it shows):

[image]

How can I set it to show only the categories for current page (or least a tree view, where I can see, where the categories belong to), because currently it's impossible to tell, what category belongs to which project (since the names overlap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TCA overrides](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/ExtendingTca/StoringChanges/Index.html#storing-in-the-overrides-folder) to customize the [`foreign_table_where` configuration option](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#foreign-table-where) of the `categories` field in the `tx_news_domain_model_news` table:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']['columns']['categories']['config']['foreign_table_where'] = ' AND sys_category.pid = ###CURRENT_PID###' . $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_news']['columns']['categories']['config']['foreign_table_where'];
```

Notice that you need to *prepend* your additional constraint because [the existing constraint](https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/2f36110/Configuration/TCA/tx_news_domain_model_news.php#L292) ends with a `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up setting `'parentField' => '0'` and 
 adding `'foreign_table_where' => " AND tt_news_cat.pid IN (###CURRENT_PID###)",` in the tca config, but your answer showed me how to add the correct PID in there.